# show that $P(A \cup B \cup C)$ isless than or equal to $P(A)+P(B)+P(C)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality

How to show that $$P(A\cup B\cup C)\le P(A)+P(B)+P(C)$$

Comment: what are your own thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Hint. Note that
$X\cup Y=X\cup (Y\cap X^c)$. Since the sets $X$ and $Y\cap X^c$ are disjoint, it follows that
$$P(X\cup Y)= P(X)+P(Y\cap X^c)\leq P(X)+P(Y).$$

Comment: could I do it without conditional probability?

Comment: @ccnotes $B\setminus A$ means $B$ minus $A$. No conditional probability here.

Comment: oh! sorry for that

Comment: @ccnotes I changed the notations. Is it clear now?

Comment: Yes thanks, but I need sometime to think how to derive it to three union

Comment: @ccnotes Think at $Y$ as $B\cup C$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $(A\cup B)$ one event such as $D$, then use $$P(D\cup C)=P(D)+P(C)-P(D\cap C)$$ Then insert $D$ and $P(D)$, and again expand $P(D)$:

$$\begin{align}P(A\cup B\cup C)&=P(A\cup B)+P(C)-P(D\cap C)\\
&=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)+P(C)-P(A\cap B \cap C)\end{align}$$ 
Since $P(A\cap B \cap C)\ge 0$ and $P(A\cap B)\ge 0$,

$$P(A\cup B\cup C)\le P(A)+P(B)+P(C)$$